# Why ∅ is not a Vector Space (over a arbitrary field F)?

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't understand why the null set ∅ is not a vector space like it obeys all the vector space axioms namely commutativity of addition, associativity of addition and multiplication (with scalar from F),existence of additive inverse, multillicative identity (1v = v for all v ∈ V (vector space)), distributive proerties and existence of additive identity.

Comment: What is the zero vector/additive identity?

Comment: By definition, a vector space is nonempty: it has an element called $0$.

Comment: More generally, $\{0\}$ plays the same role for vector spaces as $\varnothing$ for the sets. It also plays the same (dual) role as the one element set $\{\ast\}$

Comment: There exists an element 0 ∈ V, called the zero vector, such that v+0 = v for all v ∈ V. I'm unable to see why this implies that 0 must belong to the vector space V

Comment: @AbelianGroup It says so right in your statement: $0\in V$.

Comment: Moreover $V$ is an abelian group, hence nonempty by definition

Comment: Okay I get it know. I think I was confused by the use of quantifiers here.

Comment: $\{0\}$ is the smallest Vector Space by definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{0\}$ is a vector space over any field, but $\emptyset $ is none since it does not contain the additive neutral element.